# Define an element of an array using values of other elements in the same array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to define an element in a single dimensional array as (e.g.) the sum of two other elements.

I have tried this:

```
$results = array(
0 => 5,
1 => 10,
2 => $results[0] + $results[1]
);
```

But `$results[2]` returns empty.

What is the correct way to reference other elements of the current array?

This is an abstraction of a more situation - the general need is to be able to define elements as a function of sibling elements.

Comment: You first have to assign the other 2 values! Then you can access them! e.g. `$results = [5, 10];
 $results[] = $results[0] + $results[1];
 print_r($results);`

Comment: Ah... of course. Thank you. Want to make that an answer and I'll close the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to assign the other 2 values, otherwise you can't access them until you assigned it to the variable.

So just do it like this:

```
$results = [5, 10];
$results[] = $results[0] + $results[1];
print_r($results);
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 10 [2] => 15 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think no way to do it in dis way, because you are traYng to obtain a element, which aren't yet defined.
I think the only way is if you set some constant value in definition, and after the definition replace the value:

```
$results = array(
    0 => 5,
    1 => 10,
    2 => 0
);
$result[2] = $results[0] + $results[1];
```